# Is it a right usage calling SetReadDeadline in another routine?

Tags: go, goroutine

In most examples, `SetReadDeadline` is called before calling `net.Conn.Read()`.

In my program, to intterupt my `net.Conn.Read()`, I call `net.Conn.SetReadDeadline(time.Now())` in another thread/routine. Is it a right way?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the documentation states:

> SetReadDeadline sets the deadline for future Read calls
> and any currently-blocked Read call.
> A zero value for t means Read will not time out.

The only way you can call SetReadDeadline for a blocked read call is from another goroutine, so this is ok.